# Record screen problem

Tags: video-recording

vivo 1902 - unable to capture the screen of this interface due to app limitation on
how to override this situation when record screen from some apps. If I use the app recorder it just blanks when I play it again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do screen recording on apps which restrict taking screenshots and recording. Your only solution will be root access, I believe.